# Conditions on the factorization of $f(x)$ so that $F[x]/(f(x))$ is a semisimple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

The question is from Dummit and Foote, 18.2. It states, "Let $F$ be a field, let $f(x) \in F[x]$ and let $R=F[x]/(f(x))$. Find necessary and sufficient conditions on the factorization of $f(x)$ in $F[x]$ so that $R$ is a semisimple ring. When $R$ is semisimple, describe its Wedderburn decomposition".

Now I know that if $$f(x)=g_1(x)^{n_1}g_2(x)^{n_2}\dotsb g_k(x)^{n_k}$$

then

$$F[x]/(f(x)) \cong F[x]/(g_1(x)^{n_1})\times F[x]/(g_2(x)^{n_2})\times\dotsb \times F[x]/(g_k(x)^{n_k})$$

however, I'm not sure where to go from here. I noticed this question: [Semisimple rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36347/semisimple-rings) tells me that for rings $R$ and $S$, $R$ and $S$ are semisimple if and only if $R\times S$ is semisimple, so it seems like it suffices to find necessary and sufficient conditions on $g_i(x)^{n_i}$ that $F[x]/(g_i(x)^{n_i})$ is semisimple, where $g_i(x)$ is some irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$. However, I'm not sure what those conditions may be (or even if it's necessary to use this fact). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reduction is good. So the problem is:

> given $g$ irreducible, when is $F[x](g(x)^n)$ semisimple?

Now $F[x]/(g(x)^n)$ is a commutative Artinian ring. What does Wedderburn-Artin tell you?

Without Wedderburn-Artin, you can observe that $F[x]/(g(x)^n)$ is a local ring, with maximal ideal $(g(x))/(g(x)^n)$. What's the Jacobson radical of a semisimple ring?

Alternatively, prove that $F[x]/(g(x)^n)$ has a single minimal ideal (use that $F[x]$ is a PID and that $g$ is irreducible).

Comment: We didn't discuss this theorem in my class, and I can't find it in Dummit and Foote, so I just googled it and read the wikipedia entry; one thing it mentions is that "Every commutative semisimple ring must be a finite direct product of fields". It seems like the converse of this is true as well; ie, if we have a commutative ring which is a finite direct product of fields, then it is semisimple. Am I correct in assuming this? If so, the problem would reduce to "When is F[x]/(g(x)^n) a finite direct product of fields". Certainly if n=1 and g(x) is linear then it's a field, but is that necessary?

Comment: @John That's correct. Note that $F[x](g(x)^n)$ is a local ring: can it be a product of rings?

Comment: Unfortunately we didn't cover "local" rings or the "Jacobson radical" either.. I'm beginning to wonder why we skipped to this chapter if it's building off of something we didn't cover... but regardless, is there any other way to work through this without making reference to these things?

Comment: @John A semisimple ring is the sum of its minimal ideals; the ring $F[x]/(g(x)^n)$ has a single minimal ideal (use the fact that $F[x]$ is a PID).